# display results of SQL SERVER queries on one data gridview with multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a stored procedure with 2 queries in it, i would like to display the result of each query on its on page on a gridview. not sure how to go about this. here is an example of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectAllBeneficiaries
AS
SELECT * FROM PPRS

SELECT NAME,ID,DATE 
FROM MASTERRECORDS
WHERE NAME IN (SELECT MASTERRECORDS.NAME FROM MASTERRECORDS)

GO;
```

here is the c# asp.net page

```
public partial class ExtractBeneficiaries : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostbankConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        //Create the SQLCommand object
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SelectAllBeneficiaries") { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };       
        SqlDataReader reader;
        con.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = reader;
            //Bind the data
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or a Windows Form Porject? I would use a SQLDataAdapter and put results into a DAtaTable.  Then use the DataTable as the datasource.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: ASP.NET page , how can i bind each query to the gridview if i put each query in its own stored procedure?

Comment: You can create a DataSet.  Then add two tables to the DataSet. Each table will be the results of a different query.            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

Comment: how do i bind the dataset to the gridview?

Comment: See following : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-Populate-GridView-using-DataSet-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Thank you , your solution helped :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading first result, you can use

```
reader.NextResult();
```

to read the next result. This way you can process multiple recordset that are returned from the stored procedure.

In your case you can get the result and bind the datasource same way you have done for the first grid (`GridView2`).

You can read more about this at [**How To Handle Multiple Results by Using the DataReader in Visual C# .NET**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311274/how-to-handle-multiple-results-by-using-the-datareader-in-visual-c-net)

Comment: do i add it to my code like this: if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            //Bind the data
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        reader.NextResult();

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

Comment: i have one gridview , i want to display results on different pages page 1 shows results of the first select statement and page 2 of the gridview show results of second select statement

Comment: In that case you need to have two separate sp and tow separate grid one on each page.

Comment: u meant show each result on separate grid page? how do i do that?